# How to draw relationship between servlet classes

Tags: class, servlets, database-design, uml, class-diagram

Here is my database diagram
[image]

Here is the class diagram that I made
[image]

**EDIT:**
Say there are 3 modules users, profile and company and all these 3 modules requires category e.g. users category, profile category, company category.

1) May I make one separate category module and insert it in one table as I displayed in my database diagram above OR

2) May I use one category module and reuse it for each module as well as store categories in 3 different tables for example users_category, profile_category or company_category table(s)? In this case I shall make one category module and will reuse it 3 times for each time to store data in 3 different tables

In my view both are correct but the issue that I am thinking is in case of (1) if there is problem with categories module then all other 3 modules i.e. users, profile and company will suffer whereas if I use (2) then if there is problem with one category for example users_category then other modules will not suffer

Furthermore, I am looking for expert advise that how and which type of relationship exists between java Controller, Formatter and DAO classes

Please advise and thanks in anticipation

Comment: I wouldn't know how to answer 1) without knowing the business requirements. Reg. 2) What classes are you confused about?

Comment: 1) There are different modules that are using category. I have written example in the pictures for example: Module users has category=>Account type that has sub categories => Free, Paid, Platinum etc. (2) I display a picture of my classes i.e. Categories, CategoriesDAO and CategoriesFormatter. Have I made accurate relationship??

Comment: @ThomasKilian please check my question again as this time I tried to provide exact details. Its really difficult sometimes to write a question

Comment: But that's an important point. Unclear questions can't be answered clearly. Maybe someone with servlet background has better ideas. For me the info provided is not sufficient.

Comment: @ThomasKilian I realize I don't have enough power of writing being a not native English speaker but can you please advise me what is missing or what more I can provide to understand my question clearly?

Comment: I see your problem (I'm also not a native English speaker). You use the term "module" but I don't know what that means (in this context).

Comment: @ThomasKilian Say Users is one module that will be used to deal all operations or user interaction with the system whereas profile module will deal only will the classes/packages that will deal with profiles and in the same way company

Comment: So that's a class. Then why are you talking of modules?

Comment: This is not class but collection of classes in package users for example UserController, UserFormatter and UserDAO classes